# using sequel jdbc in ruby to connect to microsoft sql server 2012 - running into error com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver not loaded

Tags: ruby, sql-server, jdbc, sequel

I am trying to connect to Microsoft sQL Server 2012 database in ruby using the sequel gem.

This is what I have

```
require "sequel:
require "activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter"

@db = Sequel.connect("jdbc:sqlserver://<host>;database=<dbname>;user='<userid>';password='pwd'")
```

When I run this I get the error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver not loaded.
```

How do I load the driver?

Thanks!

Comment: You combine sequel with a activerecord-adapter. Why do you expect this should work? Why do you need jdbc to connect to a MSSQL?

Comment: It doesn't have to be jdbc. I'm new to Ruby please be gentle :) I just want to connect to Microsoft SQL Server. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to require the driver jar file manually before calling `Sequel.connect`:  `require 'path/to/sqljdbc4.jar'`.  This is true for all Sequel jdbc subadapters where there isn't a corresponding `jdbc-*` gem wrapping the jar.

Answer (score 2):

You combine sequel with an activerecord adapter.

Sequel has its own [JDBC-adapter](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-adapters/classes/Sequel/JDBC/Database.html). The [documentation](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/opening_databases_rdoc.html#label-jdbc+) mentions:

> Houses Sequel's JDBC support when running on JRuby.

Are you working with JRuby?

---

There are different possibilities to connect a MSSQL-DB with sequel. In your comment you answered you don't need JDBC.

My preferred version is using [tinytds](http://rubygems.org/gems/tiny_tds) (you must install the gem in addition to sequel.)

An excerpt from my code:

```
    db = Sequel.tinytds(
      :host     =>  connectiondata[:server], 
      :database=> connectiondata[:database],      
      :user       => connectiondata[:username],  #No SSO possible
      :password=> connectiondata[:password],
    )      
    db.test_connection  #force exception if problem occured
```

An alternative is ADO, but with ADO I had problems in the past.

```
  db = Sequel.connect(
    :adapter=>'ado', 
    :host     =>connectiondata[:server], 
    :database=>connectiondata[:database], 
    #~ :user       => connectiondata[:username],  #not needed via SSO
    #~ :password=>connectiondata[:password],    #not needed via SSO
    #:encoding =>Encoding::UTF_8,  #only MySQL
  )
  db.test_connection  #force exception if problem occured
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issues and found that simply downloading and copying the jdbcsql driver to the jruby/lib/ directory solves the issue (I'm using Rails 4.1 with jruby on both dev and production machines).

1) Ensure you are using the proper adapter in your gemfile.

```
gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
```

2) Download the sqljdbc_4.x driver from Microsoft. Unzip and copy to ../jruby/lib/ directory on dev machine and production server.

3) Use the following in your database.yaml file:

```
production:
  host:      <your.server.address>
  adapter:   jdbc
  username:  <your_username>
  password:  <your_password>
  database:  YourDatabaseName
  driver:    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
  url:       jdbc:sqlserver://<your.sever.address>;databaseName=<YourDatabaseName>
  pool:      5
  timeout:   5000
```

I use this setup with a Mac OS X (10.10) dev machine and a Windows 2012 Server production server.

This also avoids having to install tiny_tds which can be troublesome to build under jruby.